# Bit manipulation in multi threading application

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, atomic

How can I verify the thread-safety of the bit manipulation in a multi-threaded application? I am trying to set and reset the bits of an atomic variable shared among various threads.

```cpp
std::atomic<uint8_t> bitset_;
void set(unsigned n) {
    uint8_t val = bitset_.load();
    while (!bitset_.compare_exchange_weak(val, val | (1 << n), std::memory_order_release));
}
void reset(unsigned n) {
    uint8_t val = bitset_.load();
    while (!bitset_.compare_exchange_weak(val, val & ~(1 << n), std::memory_order_release));
}
bool test(unsigned i) { return (bitset_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) >> i) & 1; }
bool allset() { return bitset_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 255; }
```

Comment: Testing concurrency is hard.  As an example, you can try just flooding it by spawning a thread for each bit position that clears and sets the bit randomly millions of times, before finally leaving the bit set, and once all threads are finished check that all bits are set.

Comment: All writing atomic operations have coherency, so you may expect `compare_exchange_weak` executing as a whole, thus preventing other operations from interfering mid-way. From this perspective your code seems safe

Comment: Why not use `fetch_or` and `fetch_and`, which work for sure?

Comment: @harold Thanks, I was not aware of `fetch_and` and `fetch_or`.